# Can not push to GitHub even after I change username and password

Tags: git, github

I have cloned one project and also change username & email (to zjffdu2), but when I try to push it to GitHub, I got the following error(it looks like it still tries to push via zjffdu), is there anything I miss? zjffdu is my global git name, while zjffdu2 is a project-specific name.

```
ERROR: Permission to zjffdu2/myproject.git denied to zjffdu.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Output of git remote -v

```
origin  https://github.com/zjffdu2/zeppelin.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/zjffdu2/zeppelin.git (push)
```

Comment: a bad url maybe?

Comment: You might not have the permissions to push with that user! Check repository settings

Comment: zjffdu is my global git name, while zjffdu2 is my project specific username, I don't understand why it still use zjffdu to push this repository. It suppose to use zjffdu2

Comment: Can you please add the outut of `git remote -v` to your question?

Comment: @UwePlonus I have updated the post

Comment: You are using the wrong username. The URL is OK so far.

Comment: @UwePlonus is right, since you are using https the git prompt ask for your username and password, you have to use `zjffdu2` as username (because that's your Github's name)

Answer (score 0):

from within the repo this should tell you which user you are

```
git config --global -l
```

this should let you change the username git is using, by opening the config file in a text editor

```
git config --global --edit
```

may ask you for a password when you interact with the remote.